How can i convert a column based on a string pattern in R using tidyverse like functions?
I want to create two columns from the given below table DATA.I want the first column (say ID1) to have all the letters or numbers before the first "-" starting from left to right and the second column (ID2) to have the first letters or numbers before the first "-" starting from right to left and to print them  as character.
val = c(1,2,3,4)
tor = c( "0001-NEW YORK , M.AVENUE, NY-U.S.A"  ,                                            
         "0023-cARAVAGGIO-MALTA"        ,                                              
         "009876-bUDAPEST-HUNGARY" ,NA)
DATA = tibble(val,tor)

the resulted table must look like this one :
| val  | ID1 | ID2 |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 1  | 0001    | U.S.A |
| 2  | 0023    | MALTA |
| 3  | 009876    | HUNGARY |
| 4  | NA    | NA |

A possible approach using separate_wider_delim():
library(tidyverse)

val = c(1,2,3,4)
tor = c( "0001-NEW YORK , M.AVENUE, NY-U.S.A"  ,                                            
         "0023-cARAVAGGIO-MALTA"        ,                                              
         "009876-bUDAPEST-HUNGARY" ,NA)
DATA = tibble(val,tor)

DATA |> 
  separate_wider_delim(tor, delim = "-", names = c("ID1", "extra", "ID2")) |> 
  select(-extra)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>     val ID1    ID2    
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  
#> 1     1 0001   U.S.A  
#> 2     2 0023   MALTA  
#> 3     3 009876 HUNGARY
#> 4     4 <NA>   <NA>

Created on 2024-04-03 with reprex v2.1.0

if i had spaces inside the tor column how this will affect the separate_wider_delim ?

Add |> mutate(across(everything(), str_squish)) if there are spaces at the start or end of ID1 or ID2 for any row.
